# Deploying Flask App on AWS Beanstalk Errors? Internal server error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Flask App on AWS Beanstalk. The app has already been deployed to other services and works fine, but each time I try to deploy on beanstalk I get the following error "attributeerror: module 'enum' has no attribute 'intflag'". I've tried all the typical fixes, ie pip3/pip uninstall enum34 and it's returned that there's no package named 'enum34' installed. I also tried unsetting the PYTHONPATH to no avail as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like your code is trying to access the IntFlag class in Python 3.4. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) this class was first added in Python 3.6.

It looks like the [latest supported version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.python) is now 3.6 so - if you were to try again using this new solution stack - I think it should work. For reference, past versions can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-python.html).